# Please explain the difference in the printfs below

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

```
printf("%x\n",(const uint8_t *)0x0D);
printf("%x\n",(const uint8_t)0x0D);
printf("%x\n",(uint8_t *)0x0D);
printf("%x\n",0x0D);
```

They all give me `D` . What is it the significance of the `const` and the `*`s here?

Comment: Hope Helps http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: Turn your compiler's warnings to maximum and you'll see what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Those with pointer casts are wrong. This is the main difference. Compile your code with `-Wall` option. GCC will gives you all infos.

Comment: None of those are correct. The last one should have the suffix `U`, because `x` expects an unsigned type. but 0x0D is signed.

Comment: @2501 OP's code is correct in 4th line.  See C11 §6.5.2.2 11.  When a ... value is passed that is in range of `int` and `unsigned`, it makes no difference.

Comment: @chux Recusive functions are irrelevant to this case.

Comment: Text for fprintf specifiers clearly says: *If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.*. The conversion specifier `x`, without any length modifiers, requires the type: *unsigned int*. The type in the last example in the question is *int*. Int and unsigned int are distinct types. Therefore, undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 Incorrect on my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909273/please-explain-the-difference-in-the-printfs-below?noredirect=1#comment61388464_36909273).  C11 §6.5.2.2 11 should have been C11 §6.5.2.2 6.  The key part being "one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%x` format specifier experts the argument to be of type `unsigned int`.

In your case,

```
 printf("%x\n",(const uint8_t)0x0D);
 printf("%x\n",0x0D);
```

arguments will be promoted (default promotion rule) to match the type, but in case of

```
 printf("%x\n",(const uint8_t *)0x0D);  //supplying a pointer
 printf("%x\n",(uint8_t *)0x0D);        //supplying a pointer
```

You'll invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as per `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [...] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined. [...]

Comment: *arguments will be promoted (default promotion rule) to match the type* This is not correct. In the first printf the constant is, after the cast, promoted to int, which doesn't match specifier `x`, and in the second the type of the constant is already int, which also doesn't match `x`. The part of the Standard you quoted, explains why those examples are ub.

Comment: @2501 The first is unsigned type, why is it not ok?

Comment: @fluter Because it is promoted to int, using default argument promotions.

Comment: @2501 It might not still be UB for this particular case. When standard describes the default argument promotions, there is an exception regarding signed and unsigned types: *"..  the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
— one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;"*. In this case `0x0D` is representable in both types.

Comment: @user694733 That doesn't apply in this case. See the full text above the snippet you posted. Function printf most certainly has a prototype, and that only applies to actual named parameters. Anyhow, 7.21.6. p9 is clear: *If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.*

Comment: @2501 Ok, that is true. But standard is a bit conflicting in this issue. 7.21.6.1 paragraph 7 says *"**hh** Specifies that a following **d, i, o, u, x, or X** conversion specifier applies to a
**signed char** or **unsigned char** argument (the argument will have
been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be
converted to **signed char** or **unsigned char** before printing);"* That would seem to allow `unsigned char c = 8; printf("%hhx", c);`, which conflicts with our earlier interpretation.

Comment: @2501 C11 §6.5.2.2 6 does apply here

Comment: @2501 In that case, can you please explain §6.2.5/9, _"The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the
corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the same value in each
type is the same."_

Comment: @user694733 What you're quiting is text for the length modifier: `hh`, and how it applies to different specifiers. The relevant text here is the one from the conversion specifier `x` itself in paragraph 8.

Comment: @chux I agree, it applies. It specifies default argument promotions, which happen here. And the text in 7.21.6.p9 specifies that the examples are undefined behavior, which I have already explained why.

Comment: @user694733 `unsigned char c = 8; printf("%hhx", c);` is valid code. It is specified in the very text you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

`%x` specifies in `printf` is used to print the unsigned integer argument as hexadecimal notation. That's why you see all print 'D'. But only the 4th form is correct.

```
printf("%x\n",(const uint8_t *)0x0D); // undefined behavior, converting integer constant to a pointer
printf("%x\n",(const uint8_t)0x0D);  // ok, but not necessary
printf("%x\n",(uint8_t *)0x0D); // undefined behavior
printf("%x\n",0x0D); // ok
```

Note the function does not require constant in any case, so `const` is simply useless, note `const` in C does not make constant, it only defines something as read only.

Comment: implementation defined? Can you quote something?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for reminding, it is UB, I was just thinking about the convertion, not printf's expectation.

Comment: oh, my mistake :-)

Comment: The second and last printf are not ok. See my comment to the other answer.